# Select a single cell in a UITableView to go to a UITableView to display different student lists data

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, viewcontroller

Updated

I want to select each row to go to ViewController that has a TableView to display different student lists data, but for my code, it will display the same list as I created a new student object, How do I fix this?
The problem is I don't have a list of student data ahead until I click a single class cell to go to next ViewController, then I'll have a plus button to add student into a TableView.

**ManageViewController** Class:

```
class ManageViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var classList = [Class]()
var selectedClass: StudentData?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "Manage Classes"
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Class> = Class.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let classList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.classList = classList
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {}


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Add class button action:

```
@IBAction func onAddTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Class", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (classListTF) in
        classListTF.placeholder = "Enter Class"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
        guard let list = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        print(list)
        let subject = Class(context: PersistenceService.context)
        subject.class_name = list
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        self.classList.append(subject)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Code for class cell selection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // Unwrap that optional
    if let label = cell?.textLabel?.text {
        print("Tapped \(label)")
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "studentInfoView", sender: self)
}
```

**StudentListViewController** class:

```
class StudentListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var studentList = [StudentData]()
var selectedStudent: StudentData?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<StudentData> = StudentData.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let studentList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.studentList = studentList
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {}


}

@IBAction func addStudentTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Student", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (studentListTF) in
        studentListTF.placeholder = "Enter name"
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
        guard let student = alert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }
        print(student)
        let person = StudentData(context: PersistenceService.context)
        person.student_name = student
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        self.studentList.append(person)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert,animated: true)
}
```

I have updated my additional code for **ManageViewController** class and **StudentInfoViewContrller** class. Sorry I'm a new Ios programmer.

Comment: You are performing `segue` to a `view` with identifier `studentInfoView` no matter what `cell` is selected so you will always see the same `view`.

Comment: Yes, Is it better to have the same ViewController, but shows different data, no matter what cell is selected, or have different ViewControllers ?

Comment: Yes, if the layout is same then it must be a single `ViewController` but different data based on the selected cell.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I pass data into this view, the others are passing same data too.

Comment: Other who? We have no information how you are passing data so can't tell much.

Comment: @Kamran I just updated the code of the action after creating new cell into TableView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183277/discussion-between-hung-nguyen-and-kamran).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183329/discussion-between-hung-nguyen-and-kamran).

Comment: Hey @Son Thanh are you able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You should add in an additional condition to be able to go to a different view based on the selected row like the ff:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toViewA", sender: self)
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toViewA", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. The problem is I don't know ahead how many rows I have because I create them manually, my app is to create a list of classes from a button, then click a single class cell to create new list of student in this class.

Comment: I see, so the main problem is not really presenting a different view depending on what row was selected but rather presenting a view with different data which is based from which row was selected. In that case D V's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the student data to your next view **UIViewController** using `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` delegate.

In your **UIViewController** which has the **UITableView** with all the students listed, have a variable declared to keep the student from the table, along with your `studentList` variable.

```
var selectedStudent: StudentData?
```

After that, in the **UITableView** delegate method `didSelectRowAt`, set the value for the `selectedStudent`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Make sure that the selected inexPath.row is within the bounds of the studentsList array.
    if indexPath.row < studentList.count {
        selectedStudent = studentList[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "studentInfoView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then, in the same **UIViewController**, assign the `student` property of your **UIViewController** which shows the student's details.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "studentInfoView" {
        // Replace 'StudentInfoViewController' with your detail UIViewController class name.
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? StudentInfoViewController
        destinationVC?.student = selectedStudent
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have the `student` property declared in your **StudentInfoViewController** (or, whatever you are calling it).

```
class StudentInfoViewController: UIViewController {

    var student: StudentData?

    // .......
    // .......
}
```

Then, in the `viewDidLoad()` or any other setup method in the **StudentInfoViewController**, you can setup the details of the student on the screen.

Comment: Since the selectedStudent variable in StudentInfoViewController class, but the the UITableView delegate method didSelectRowAt is in ManageViewController class, how can I use the variable?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, `selectedStudent` should not be in **StudentInfoViewController**; it should be in the controller with **UITableView** delegate methods. It should be in **ManageViewController**, as per your comment.

Comment: I was confused because at the end where you said **var student: StudentData?** in the **StudentInfoViewController: UIViewContrller**,I did the same as you recommend, created selectedStudent variable in ManageViewController, then implemented the **func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)**, but it gives me error **Cannot assign value of type 'StudentData?' to type '[StudentData]'**

Comment: Please share the location you are having this error at, with screenshots.

Comment: @D V studentList is also in **StudentListViewController** class, so how can I use it in the **ManageViewContrller** class?

Comment: I have updated the question and additional codes, please check it out.

Comment: The problem is I don't have student data until I go to the next view controller, because I need to create student objects after choosing a single class.

Comment: @HungNguyen What do you need to create student objects? For example, if it is the id of the class, then that's the variable you declare in the next view controller and update/set this value in `prepare(for segue: )`. The next view controller would take care of creating the student based on the class id you just sent. The key here is that you yourself can define what you can send to the next view controller.

Comment: @irs8925 I need to select a single class cell, then go to next ViewController to create a student object.

Comment: @HungNguyen cool. additional information we've provided should suffice then.

Comment: Hey @DV I was following your step but I whenever I created new student in one of the class cell, the other class cell has that student too.

Comment: I just realized that I did ask wrong question, I don't actually need to pass data between ViewControllers, instead I need to create student object whenever I click on one of the class cell. @DV